# My images are broken not showing up in HTML code

Tags: html, image

Can I please ask for small help

I have made email template that I want to use with my website

Image folder is called zlab and I uploaded in root directory of my website ( as well as same directory as email file it self file )

When I test to send email image is broken

I added this code in html to call image from root folder

when email comes trough to my inbox image code looks like this:
`http:////zlab/logo.png`

I don't know why website is adding: `http:///zlab/logo.png`

it should be adding my actual website link which is: `https://fleeped.com/zlab/logo.png`

Here is the code

```
<td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"><img src="/zlab/logo.png" alt style="display:block;border:0;outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;" width="125"></td>
```

Any ideas why is it not using actual url and only posting image folder name instead?

Thank you

Comment: Hi David Thank you for trying to help I did add the code but don't know what happend here is the code.   <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"><img src="./zlab/logo.png" alt style="display:block;border:0;outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;" width="125"></td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I test to send email

An email is not a website.

When you have a website that includes an incomplete URL, the browser attempts to complete that URL for you.  So when you have this:

```
/zlab/logo.png
```

The browser infers the rest of the URL from the current URL of the loaded page, to complete it as something like:

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/zlab/logo.png
```

But in an *email* there is no such "current URL of the loaded page".  There is no context from which to infer information about the incomplete URL.  All it has is this:

```
/zlab/logo.png
```

That value, by itself, isn't enough information for the email client to find the image.  At best, and this behavior may differ by email client, it *might* at least assume an `http://` prefix.  But it's certainly not going to know the domain or anything else about the intended URL.

You need to put the complete URL in the email:

```
https://fleeped.com/zlab/logo.png
```

Comment: Hi David so there is no code I can add in front in order for email to fetch domain? So if my image folder is in root directory code will know to grab domain for that root directory ?

Comment: @JaneLove: The code you would add is the protocol and domain: `https://fleeped.com`  When you say: *"grab domain for that root directory"* - What exactly do you mean?  A directory (part of a file system) and a domain (part of a URL) are entirely different things.  Though the path of a URL can and commonly does directly map to part of the server's file system, how would one expect to infer the domain name from that path?  This is simply a matter of having to provide the client (in this case an email) with the information it needs.  That information is the URL of your image.

Comment: Hi again David thank you for that detailed report, I was trying to achieve somehow code so that images are grabbed from root directory, because I will be selling this email templates and it's not a great practice to put in tutorial change all Fleeped.com url to your own I just taught user who desides to buy the template can replace image in image folder and this would load down logo for them and any other image they wish to change. Thank you for your help